# Physical Significance of non-normalized state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, observables, normalization

What does the coefficient physically mean for an operator that isn't an observable. For an observable the coefficient is the eigenvalue and is the value that will be measured, but for operators that aren't observables they can't be measured. An example is the Ladder Operator where $a\vert n \rangle = \sqrt{n+1}\vert n+1 \rangle$. Here the ladder operator maps the state to a new one, but now there is a coefficient in front of $\sqrt{n+1}$ which means the new state isn't normalized, what is the physical significance of it?

Comment: why would you expect it to be normalized?

Comment: I guess the question at the root of my original question, is what does a non normalized function mean physically? Is it purely mathematical, or does that coefficient manifest itself physically?

Comment: The question written in the title and the question that you wrote now in the comments are different. I would suggest to edit the title accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether an operator $\hat{A}$ is an observable or not, if $\hat{A}|\psi\rangle = a | \psi\rangle$ then $a$ is simply its eigenvalue. That's the definition of the eigenvalues, it has nothing to do with whether the operator is an observable or not. Further, simply mathematically, what they represent are the diagonal elements of the operator in its eigenbasis. Clearly, since they are not observables, they wouldn't correspond to any physical measurement.

However, the fact that when you act such an operator on its eigenstate, the resulting state isn't normalized is nothing peculiar. This is what happens with operators who represent observables as well. For example, all the eigenvalues of the momentum operator are of non-unit absolute value except for $\pm 1$, of course. There is nothing wrong here, they are supposed to be Hermitian operators, not unitary. The interesting thing that Hermitian operators (observables) do is that their exponentiation will produce unitary operators who preserve the norm when acted upon a state--and thus are viable candidates to represent different symmetry transformations. For example, $e^{-i\hat{p}x}$, the exponentiation of the momentum operator, is unitary and produces translations in space.

---

**Edit**

Regarding the action of non-observable operators on states other than their eigenvalues, e.g., $\hat{a}^\dagger|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$, again, there is no direct physical meaning here. You can make sense of them in formalism in a mathematical language. In this case, it can be seen as the matrix element of the operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$ in the number-basis, for example.

Comment: I was more interested in what the coefficient means when a non observable operator isn't acting on an eigenstate like the ladder operator. It maps one state to another, but now there is a coefficient in front. What does that coefficient mean, does the coefficient itself change the physical state?

Comment: @talgif I see. I'll update my answer later. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @talgif I have added a few lines to address your point.

Answer (score 1):

I think may be confusing two things here.  One is the state, which is taken as normalized, and the other is the action of an operator on the state, which may not result in another normalized state.

Maybe the simplest example of that of an average value: given an operator $\hat A$, its average is $\langle \psi\vert\hat A\vert \psi\rangle$ and even if the states are normalized the average value is general will not be $1$.  In fact in the simplest examples - say an infinite well between $0$ and $L$, we have
\begin{align}
\langle \psi_n\vert \hat x\vert\psi_n\rangle =\frac{L}{2}.
\end{align}
You can easily compute the length of the state $\hat x\vert n\rangle$: it is just
$\sqrt{\langle n \vert \hat x^2\vert n\rangle}$ and so will not be $1$ even if $\vert {n}\rangle $ has length 1.
Likewise the average value of the position of an electron in a hydrogen atom is usually of the size of the Bohr radius, and so not $1$.

The matrix elements of the operator $\hat A$ is
\begin{align}
\langle n\vert \hat A\vert m\rangle
\end{align}
and will enter into the computations of probabilities of transitions, for instance.  There’s no reason to suggest that, even if $\vert m\rangle$ is normalized so that $\langle m\vert m\rangle=1$, then $\hat A\vert m\rangle$ is a normalized state.

As a final example, suppose you find that $\hat A\vert n\rangle$ has length $1$, then the operator $\hat B=\alpha\hat A$ acting on $\vert n\rangle$ will clearly give a vector of length $\alpha$, whatever value of $\alpha$ you choose,

Answer (score 1):

Normalisation has no effect on physical states. We say that states are rays in Hilbert space, where a ray is an equivalence class of all nonzero vectors which are identical up to a complex scalar factor. Any vector in the ray chosen as a state vector representing the the state. We usually pick a normalised vector, but then phase is still not determinate. Multiplicative factors only become important in superpositions.

This is so because all physical predictions of quantum mechanics are probabilities given by the Born rule. If the state at time $t$ is known to be $|f\rangle$, then the probability that a measurement at time $t$ will give the result $|g\rangle$ is given by
$$P(g|f) = \frac{ |\langle g |f\rangle |^2} {\langle g |g\rangle\langle f |f\rangle} $$

In the case of operators, like ladder operators, which do not correspond to observable quantities, normalisation is chosen for convenience. It has no physical meaning.